# Excel Skill Tracker with automatic suggestion?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file in order to track each skill level for each person. Example:

George | Skill 1 | Skill 2 | Skill 3 | Skill 4

Michael | Skill 1 | Skill 2 | Skill 3 | Skill 4

William | Skill 1 | Skill 2 | Skill 3 | Skill 4

The table has data validation with ✔️ and ❌. What I want is when a person needs someone that has knowledge in skill 1, he can press a button/search in a field skill 1 and Excel shows/suggests him the user that has ✔️ for skill 1 and also the most ✔️ overall. Basically, if a new person needs help with something, he can find in a second the best person with skill 1 and overall skill that can help him.

Is this something that can be done in Excel maybe using Macros or VBA? If not, can this be done in another software but still have the big table available?

Thanks a lot for your time and any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: This can be done by array formula, i had my names in A, Skills 1 to 3 in B to D, and used Y and N for skills and used something like so.    This would be a good start  `=MIN(IF(($B$2:$B$6="Y")*(($C$2:$C$6="Y")*($D$2:$D$6="Y"))>0,ROW($B$2:$B$6)))`

Comment: Also, VBA is possible.  Have you made a start with either?